# Creating seat plan with css

Tags: css, positioning

I would like to create a seating plan by using css. As a box, I used this tutorial's css file http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/create-a-document-icon-with-css3/.

Firstly, when I'm trying to add second box in a same row, it will skip a line, 
then I changed box's css with the following:

```
.docIcon {
   background: #15cd2f;

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #caffb2 0, #15cd2f 15%, #caffb2 40%, #caffb2 70%, #15cd2f 100%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #caffb2 0, #15cd2f 15%, #caffb2 40%, #caffb2 70%, #15cd2f 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #caffb2 0, #15cd2f 15%, #caffb2 40%, #caffb2 70%, #15cd2f 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #caffb2 0, #15cd2f 15%, #caffb2 40%, #caffb2 70%, #15cd2f 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(top, #caffb2 0, #15cd2f 15%, #caffb2 40%, #caffb2 70%, #15cd2f 100%);

   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   display: block;
   width: 26px;
   height: 50px;

   float:left;
   text-align:center;
}
```

but then the problem is, I need row's to be centered instead of standing on left.

How should I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.docIcon {display: inline-block;}
```

Then wrap your boxes in a container that is centered and has `text-align: center`

Comment: I also tried this, but it is still on the left;

<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>24</a>
  <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>23</a>
</div>

and the content of the container is:

.container{
 text-align: center;
}

Comment: oh, and be sure to get rid of the `float: left`

Answer (score 1):

DA is right ....
here see this http://jsfiddle.net/jzjVT/3/
if this is what you are trying to do..